# Как выполнить асинхронную загрузку нескольких файлов?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, webclient

Существует два списка (Общий, Дополнительный). Когда этот код выполняется, ссылки передаются из одного списка в другой через 3-5 секунд. Но так как метод выполняется асинхронно, он не ждет, пока Общий список будет заполнен элементами, следовательно, при вызове метода Download() - он загружает не все файлы, а столько, сколько успевает записать ссылок в Общий список.

Если использовать MethodName().Wait ИЛИ .Result (внутри метода, чтобы получать ссылки синхронно) - замораживается форма и ничего не выполняется.

Как исправить код, чтобы не ждать получения всех ссылок сразу, а сделать это следующий образом (получил ссылку - загрузил файл, и в то же время в список добавляются новые ссылки). Или дождаться, получения всех ссылок, а затем выполнить загрузку файлов по этим ссылкам.

```
    List<string> AllLinks;

    List<string> PartLinks = new List<string>() {
        "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/single/krasnaia_panda_zhivotnoe_sneg_249546_3840x2400.jpg",
        "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/single/gorod_zdaniia_voda_249525_3840x2160.jpg",
        "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/single/ozero_les_sneg_130421_2560x1080.jpg"
    };

    Random random = new Random();
    private async Task GetLinks(List<string> links) {
        AllLinks = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++) {
            AllLinks.Add(PartLinks[i]);
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(3, 5));
            //  Добавить новую ссылку в Общий список через 3-5 секунд
           // В реальной программе это время уходит на отправку файлов через multipart request
        }
    }

    private void Download(List<string> links, string outputpath) {
        for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++) {
            new WebClient().DownloadFile(new Uri(links[i]),
                Path.Combine(outputpath, $"{i}.jpg"));
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await GetLinks(PartLinks);
        Download(AllLinks, @"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop");
    }
```

Comment: Это StackOverflow на русском. Здесь вопросы нужно задавать только на русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`.

Создадим простой метод загрузки

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // экземпляр клиента создается один раз, а не на каждый запрос

private async Task DownloadFileAsync(string url, string path)
{
    using var fs = File.Create(path);
    using var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(url);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

И вызовем его параллельно для всего списка

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await GetLinks(PartLinks);
    var tasks = AllLinks.Select((link, i) => DownloadFileAsync(link, Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop", $"{i}.jpg"));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // загрузка завершена
}
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, почему при использовании индекса i, для перебора элементов другого списка, возникает исключение "Индекс находился вне границ массива"?

Пример, как было (Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop", $"{i}.jpg"));).
Пример, как стало (Path.Combine(outputpath, $"{files[i].FileName}.jpg")));)

Comment: @Ilya Потому что в массиве `files` меньше элементов, чем в списке `AllLinks`.